# Overwriting css rule doesn't work

Tags: html, css

So I have a label styled in the Pure css Framework like this:

```
.pure-form-aligned .pure-control-group label {
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 10em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0; }
```

I want to "overwrite" width, so BELOW I do this:

```
.form label {//note the dot, this is a class
  width: auto; }
```

And in html I have:

```
<form name="form" method="post" class="pure-form pure-form-aligned form">
 <div class="pure-control-group">
              <input type="checkbox" id="form_permissions_1" name="form[permissions][]" value="1" checked="checked" />
              <label for="form_permissions_1">Tworzenie nowego użytkownika</label>
 <div>
```

Note, that I added the "form" class to the declaration.

Why it doesn't work? I used to do this all the time in the past.

Update: I added more html code.

Comment: `.pure-form-aligned .pure-control-group label` has a higher specificity than  `.form label`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about "specificity" but forgot its name and I thought it is only true for id having more "strength" than class, but it seems it's much more. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the first selector has more strength than the second.

This:

```
.pure-form-aligned .pure-control-group label
```

Is deeply than

```
.form label
```

Then the first is overriding the second. You must to put more specific classnames in the selector or use `!important`

```
.form label { width: auto !important; }
```

OR

```
.form .anotherclass label
```

Comment: Thanks, the auto !important;  trick did the job, although I've read somewhere that it is "bad", but don't remember why. Anyway - I'll accept the answer as soon as Stackoverflow allows me (in 7 minutes). Thanks again!

Comment: The use of `!important` is in my opinion, bad practice.

Comment: The use of `!important` is bad practice in opinion of all, but seems that OP doesn't have a more specific structure to make it deeply

Comment: @konrad_firm the bad things is explained in this answer. You have a link from paulie_D comment to check the specifity

Comment: @XmlmXmlmX  - theoretically I can add a new class to the form declaration, but doing this only to make overwriting working is a bit hacky for me thus I believe I'm justified :)

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude, funny: on w3c.org I found this "Note: Repeated occurrances of the same simple selector are allowed and do increase specificity." so just to test I did ".form.form label..." in my css and it worked:) But is less readable.

Comment: Yeah, but is better if you change the classname `.form` to a form id `#form`, with this way you don't need to use `!important` or repeated classnames.

Comment: Thanks, but it is supposed to be "global", and there may be more than 1 form on a single page. So !important is the way I think.

Comment: `!important` is almost *never* the way.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I forgot to accept your answer, I did it now.

Comment: @konrad_firm Thank you!